# Ensure es6 find don't break when property is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code

```
const arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'anything'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'something'
}]

const target = [1]
```

I want to find whether target has 1 and I want the name property value

I'll do

```
arr.find(o => target.includes(o.id)).name
```

but this will break if

`arr.find(o => target.includes(o.id))` doesn't have the `name` property, it break the entire app and throw error.

So how to ensure this from being crashed? I can do this but it's ugly

```
const somethingValue = arr.find(o => target.includes(o.id)) && arr.find(o => target.includes(o.id)).name
```

or I have to map to ensure the `arr` always have name property, I have to do this if the `arr` is dynamic and the south comes from external party.

Any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use empty object `{}` and `||` operator.

```
(arr.find(o => target.includes(o.id)) || {}).name
```

If `find()` will return `undefined` so the expression will evaluate to `{}` and try to get `name` from `{}` which is `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Extract the result from `.find` into a variable first, and then check to see if that variable is defined:

```
const foundObject = arr.find(o => target.includes(o.id));
const somethingValue = foundObject ? foundObject.name : null;
```

Comment: yeah I know this but it's a 2 steps thing

Comment: Don't be afraid of defining variables - there's no need to create an extra object just to extract a non-existent property